# Is there a way to get byte[] from ExcelWorkBook without saving it to disk first

Tags: c#, excel, .net-2.0, excel-interop

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to create Excel file in C#, append data, change format and all.
Now I save data into file, but what I want is to write bytes into stream, so basically I don't want to write it into file then open it and then write it into stream.

I just want to write data from Excel Workbook into byte array and then return it.

So what I do now is

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
```

and I want to say something like this `xlWorkBook.GetBytes();`. So `byte[]` would be equal as `byte[]` readed from excel file with `FileStream`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what sort of application is this (ASP.NET, Windows Service...) ?

Comment: yes it does matter... another point: what Excel version is this ?

Comment: I don't see why it would be matter, I just want bytes of created excel file so I can write it into database without first writing it on File System.

Comment: And just if you know solution for any version of interop excel just tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this, except save as file then read it with filestream

Comment: Yeah your are right. Technically there is another option which is to use third party library such aspose,spire ,etc are some of the libraries which would convert into bytearray and then convert to html,pdf,etc....